# Javascript update parent content from frame

Tags: javascript, frame, updates

my issue is that I'm trying to update a `div` content (with `id="content"`) 
from frame content after it gets loaded from form submission.

Where form attribute `action="test.php"` and `target="source"` which is the frame name.

The code sample is here: [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/welcome/58278/)

The result from `test.php` is this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.parent.top.getElementById('content').innerHtml = "Western";
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a document reference:

```
window.parent.document.getElementById('content').innerHtml = "Western";
```